# XSLT 1.0 transformation overwrite or add child nodes

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2015, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to use xslt 1.0 (using visual studio 2015) transformation on the following xml.

I am given a name of the House and names and new values of the Furnitures that should be inside that House.

If a Furniture with a given name already exists, overwrite its value.
If not, create a new one.
If a Furniture is in the House but should not be overwritten, just copy it.
The order of the Furnitures that were already in the house should not be changed.

I'm not new to languages like c++,C#,JAVA, but xslt is... different.
While this is a simple task in above mentioned languages, I really struggle here.

Please help.

XML code

```
<Street>
  <House Name="house1">
    <Window>niceView</Window>
    <Furniture Name="name1">value1</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name2">value2</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name3">value3</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name4">value4</Furniture>     
  </House>
  <House>
    <Brick Name="cubrick"></Brick>
    <Furniture name="name1>value</Furniture>
  </House>
</Street>
```

XSLT beggining

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="house1" select='house1'/>
<xsl:param name="name2" select='newValue1'/>
<xsl:param name="name4" select='newValue2'/>
<xsl:param name="name10" select='newValue5'/>
...
```

The desired output is:

```
<Street>
  <House Name="house1">
    <Window>niceView</Window>
    <Furniture Name="name1">value1</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name2">newValue1</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name3">value3</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name4">newValue2</Furniture>  
    <Furniture Name="name10">newValue5</Furniture>   
  </House>
  <House>
    <Brick Name="cubrick"></Brick>
    <Furniture name="name1>value</Furniture>
  </House>
</Street>
```

Comment: I don't understand your output for the 2nd `House`.

Comment: Sry, that was a typo. That second house is simply unchanged. It may, or may not have an attribute Name. It may have anything. I am only interested in House where attribute Name=$house1.

Comment: Are you sure you need to parametrize the values as shown? This is very awkward, as you cannot easily select a parameter by its name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to. The xml is given to me in such state and I need to be able to map different Furnitures with given Name to their new values.

Comment: I am referring to the 4 `xsl:param` instructions in your XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: The XSLT stylesheet file is up to my implementation. What would you suggest?

Comment: I don't know. Where are the values of these parameters coming from? Can they be hard-coded into the stylesheet, or supplied in an external XML document? Note also that the first parameter is different from the other ones: it holds the name of the node, while the others hold text values.

Comment: They should be hard-coded. The user should be able to easily change them within the xslt sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I would suggest you consider the following approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- MODIFY THESE AS NECESSARY -->
<xsl:param name="my-house">house1</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="my-values">
    <Furniture Name="name2">newValue2</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name4">newValue4</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name10">newValue10</Furniture>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- DO NOT MODIFY FROM THIS POINT ON -->
<xsl:variable name="user-values" select="exsl:node-set($my-values)/Furniture" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="House">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:if test="@Name=$my-house">
            <!-- add missing nodes -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="$user-values[not(@Name=current()/Furniture/@Name)]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Furniture">
    <xsl:variable name="override" select="$user-values[@Name=current()/@Name]"/>
    <Furniture Name="{@Name}">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../@Name=$my-house and $override">
                <xsl:value-of select="$override" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Furniture>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following well-formed (!) example input:

**XML**

```
<Street>
  <House Name="house1">
    <Window>niceView</Window>
    <Furniture Name="name1">value1</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name2">value2</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name3">value3</Furniture>
    <Furniture Name="name4">value4</Furniture>     
  </House>
  <House>
    <Brick Name="cubrick"></Brick>
    <Furniture Name="name1">value</Furniture>
  </House>
</Street>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Street>
   <House Name="house1">
      <Window>niceView</Window>
      <Furniture Name="name1">value1</Furniture>
      <Furniture Name="name2">newValue2</Furniture>
      <Furniture Name="name3">value3</Furniture>
      <Furniture Name="name4">newValue4</Furniture>
      <Furniture Name="name10">newValue10</Furniture>
   </House>
   <House>
      <Brick Name="cubrick"/>
      <Furniture Name="name1">value</Furniture>
   </House>
</Street>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You helped me to understand some concepts I didn't even knew existed. Just one more questions: why did you use  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> is it mandatory in this script or just part of good practices?

Comment: **1.** It's good practice esp. when using the identity transform template (it reduces the number of nodes the processor needs to handle); **2.** Some processors (notably Saxon 6.5) will output empty lines if it's not included - see: http://xsltransform.net/94AbWB7